# How do I read fixed-length records in Perl?

Tags: perl, fixed-length-record

What's the best way to read a fixed length record in Perl.  I know to read a file like:

```
ABCDE 302
DEFGC 876
```

I can do

```
while (<FILE>) {
   $key = substr($_, 0, 5);
   $value = substr($_, 7, 3);
}
```

but isn't there a way to do this with read/unpack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Update: For the definitive answer, see Jonathan Leffler's answer below.

I wouldn't use this for just two fields (I'd use [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)/[unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) directly), but for 20 or 50 or so fields I like to use [Parse::FixedLength](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Parse-FixedLength/FixedLength.pm) (but I'm biased). E.g. (for your example) (Update: also, you can use $/ and <> as an alternative to read($fh, $buf, $buf_length)...see below):

```
use Parse::FixedLength;

my $pfl = Parse::FixedLength->new([qw(
  key:5
  blank:1
  value:3
)]);
# Assuming trailing newline
# (or add newline to format above and remove "+ 1" below)
my $data_length = $pfl->length() + 1;

{
  local $/ = \$data_length;
  while(<FILE>) {
    my $data = $pfl->parse($_);
    print "$data->{key}:$data->{value}\n";
    # or
    print $data->key(), ":", $data->value(), "\n";
  }
}
```

There are some similar modules that make pack/unpack more "friendly" (See the "See Also" section of Parse::FixedLength).

Update: Wow, this was meant to be an alternative answer, not the official answer...well, since it is what it is, I should include some of Jonathan Leffler's more straight forward code, which is likely how you should usually do it (see [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html)/[unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) docs and Jonathan Leffler's node below):

```
$_ = "ABCDE 302";
my($key, $blank, $value) = unpack "A5A1A3";
```

Answer (score 18):

```
my($key, $value) = unpack "A5 A3";    # Original, but slightly dubious
```

We both need to check out the options at the [unpack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/unpack.html) manual page (and, more particularly, the [pack](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/pack.html) manual page).

Since the A pack operator removes trailing blanks, your example can be encoded as:

```
my($key, $value) = unpack "A6A3";
```

Alternatively (this is Perl, so TMTOWTDI):

```
my($key, $blank, $value) = unpack "A5A1A3";
```

The 1 is optional but systematic and symmetric.  One advantage of this is that you can validate that `$blank eq " "`.

Answer (score 6):

Assume 10 character records of two five character fields per record:

```
open(my $fh, "<", $filename) or die $!;
while(read($fh, $buf, 10)) {
  ($field1, $field2) = unpack("A5 A5", $buf);
  # ... do something with data ...
}
```

Comment: This is the most simple answer

Answer (score -1):

Here's yet another way to do it:

```
while (<FILE>)
{
    chomp;
    if (/^([A-Z]{5}) ([0-9]{3})$/)
    {
        $key = $1;
        $value = $2;
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Regardless of whether your records and fields are fixed-length, if the fields are separated by uniform delimiters (such as a space or comma), you can use the split function more easily than unpack.

```
my ($field1, $field2) = split / /;
```

Look up the documentation for split. There are useful variations on the argument list and on the format of the delimiter pattern.

Comment: If any field values are less than the fixed width (although this isn't the case in his example), the string will be split for the trailing spaces as well, which is wrong. If the field value lengths are all identical, then you are correct, there is no difference between delimited and fixed-width

Comment: It's not a matter of field length. If fields can have significant whitespace, you can't split on whitespace. That's one of the points of fixed-length fields. :)